# Why I cannot instantiate this variable?

Tags: java

I have this piece of code on a JSP file :

```
// MainHomePage pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);

String pageValue=request.getParameter("page");
if((pageValue!=null) && (pageValue.compareTo("1")==0)) {
    MainHomePage pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
} else if((pageValue!=null) && (pageValue.compareTo("2")==0)) {
    MainAffittaAppartamenti pageApp = new MainAffittaAppartamenti(session);
} else {
    MainHomePage pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
}

pageApp.someMethod();
```

if i don't remove comment on the first line it said (about pageApp) "cannot find symbol"... why this? if-else will instantiate it, in any case. What am I wrong? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you have should not compile since `pageApp` is not within scope on the last line. Looks like you are confused between variable **declaration** and variable **assignment**. Java allows you to do both in the same statement, however, you may only declare a variable one time within the same scope.

If you uncomment the first declaration but still leave the others inside the `if` and `else` statements, then you will get compile time errors related to duplicate declaration. Within the `if` and `else` statement blocks you are declaring this same variable with different types. You should find, if possible, an abstract type for that variable that is shared by the two types you are instantiating (e.g. `MainHomePage` and `MainAffittaAppartamenti`) and then declare it outside the `if` and `else` blocks and in the main method scope.

For example, if `MainAffittaAppartamenti` is a sub-class to `MainHomePage` then you can do this:

```
MainHomePage pageApp; // Declare here but do not assign

String pageValue=request.getParameter("page");
if((pageValue!=null) && (pageValue.compareTo("1")==0)) {
    pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
} else if((pageValue!=null) && (pageValue.compareTo("2")==0)) {
    pageApp = new MainAffittaAppartamenti(session);
} else {
    pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
}

pageApp.someMethod();
```

Notice that in the inner blocks I did not declare the variable again (that is define it with it's type). Since, given my assumption statement, `MainAffittaAppartamenti` is a sub-class of `MainHomePage` then the assignment of that to `pageApp` is valid still.

Comment: eheh, the problems is that MainAffittaAppartamenti isnt a sub-class of  MainHomePage :) So there is a solution if they arent class/sub-class?

Comment: @markzzz - Not an easy one unless you have access to the source. If they do not share the same interface or abstract base class then you couldn't call `someMethod` on the shared variable. If you have access to the source you could create an interface with `someMethod()` or others and setup both classes to implement that interface, then declare `pageApp` with that interface.

Comment: @markzzz - Also, these may have a shared base class already - that's what I meant with "You should find ... an abstract type for that variable that is shared by the two types". If there is and that type already has `someMethod()` then you would declare with that type.

Answer (score 3):

If you comment

```
MainHomePage pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
```

There will not be any variable named pageApp available for `pageApp.someMethod();`

So compiler says ,

The `pageApp` you are creating in if else are local to block

[**About scope of variable**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html)

Comment: and how can i put it shared? (not local only into block)

Comment: uhm yes. But MainAffittaAppartamenti is not a subclass of MainHomePage. I think i can't resolve this :(

Answer (score 1):

so, you should modify your code as following:

MainHomePage pageApp;

String pageValue=request.getParameter("page");
if((pageValue!=null) && (pageValue.compareTo("1")==0)) {
    pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
} else if((pageValue!=null) && (pageValue.compareTo("2")==0)) {
    pageApp = new MainAffittaAppartamenti(session);
} else {
    pageApp = new MainHomePage(session);
}
pageApp.someMethod();

Now you work with the same pageApp that you defined in the beginning. In your version of code you created local variable that lives in block between if and else only.